# migrate a PHP app from apache to IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, migrate

I want migrate a PHP app from apache to IIS.

Is there any incompatibility between theme? (Do I need to modify my app before migration?)

Comment: Your question is overly vague. You may get better results if you try the migration, and ask for help with specific points of failure.

Comment: Yes only .htaccess file for that you need to work around. The newer version of IIS has htaccess support. But for IIS 6 you need to use this software http://iirf.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 for vagueness comment...biggest issue is likely to be managing your (include) paths - if you're migrating from Linux to Windows, that can be a pain if the app builders weren't meticulous about using relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP incompatabilities? Only if you're code accesses the [PHP apache bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apache.php).

But there are a lot of subtke differences in the way IIS behaves compared with other webservers on the same OS (tunnelling NTLM to network drive access is a corker).